# AngularJs route reaload fails in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, url

I managed to get an example app working following several examples, but theres a problem i cant seem to solve. In the angular app routes work ok like this:
`- http://localhost:8888/#/login` works

but when i reload the url i get the  Cannot GET /login error from nodeJs.

i tried doing this:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, response) {
    response.write(__dirname + '/../Client/index.html');
    response.end();
});
```

and this

```
  app.get('/login', function (req, response) {
    console.log('*****************************************');
    response.sendfile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../Client/'));
});
```

but none work, i always get the same error and in the first one it just writes the url.

I think the problem is that while in the app angular knows the routing and handle the reloads because the file is served with

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../Client/'));
```

but when the url doesnt have the angular hashtag nodejs tries to look for the url but fails. is there a way i fix this? maybe redirecting to the correct url or something, i searched for hours trying stuff but none worked, thanks for taking your time.

Comment: With the last one, the express static one: do you access localhost/login? (directly by curl, browser, whatever). Could you try avoiding node JS to serve static files, like using `python -m http.server` on the app folder, and check if you angular app now works?

Comment: thanks for the answer. the last one works only with /, any other route fails. avoiding nodejs wont solve it, as i need node for the jsons, auth, etc. i was thinking of doing the same as in the last line but with every single path the angular app has, but it would be horrible, also, im really new to nodejs/angularjs, i have a hard time understanding some thing, but ill do my best

Comment: I just suggest you to serve your angular application files without node to let your node application be simply a web service. It saves me lot of times at my beginning, and help me to go inside these two news technologies without any confusion. If you don't like to use python embedded server or whatever, then you can have a nodeJS that only serve static files on port 80 and another nodeJS that works as a WS on another port, like 8080. Give it a try.

Comment: ill try to create another nodejs app, but i think it wont solve it, unless this app has all the routes as the angular app. the only route im serving is the one above, all others are handled by angular and node is just a ws like you said. ill report after i go that way, thank!

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated from the fact that Angular will rewrite the window.location at runtime while you are using your application starting from the root `localhost/` and routing you to `localhost/login` (without calling the server with a GET).
So, when you refresh, the browser didn't know that the url was written by javascript, so he calls the node server that reject the request.
I other word: you need to start your navigation always from the root.. but this is unusable.

So I figure out how to develop a single project with Angular (4 in my case) for the front-end and nodejs-express for the back-and.

I've tested this solution for redirect with fragment from different source like auth0 and the use of JSON Web Token.

This let me to deploy this application easily to a single heroku instance.

**NodeJs Configuration**

The first middlewere have to be the path where the Angular's app is build

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + './dist'));
```

Then I have configured express-jwt *(the regular expression is for all the url that not starts with "/api")*

```
app.use(expressJwt({secret: appConfig.SecurityJwt}).unless({
  path: [
    '/api/v1/login',
    /^(?!\/api).*/gm
  ]
}));
```

Then the business logic of front end:

```
app.post('/api/v1/login', ...
app.get('/api/v1/myOtherServices' ....
```

And in the very end of routing configuration, even after the custom error handler:

```
app.use(appHandleError);


app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: './dist'});
});

app.listen(4200);
```

**Angular routing**

I did not do anything particular here:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'authenticated', component: ActivatePageComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false, enableTracing: false})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Then in the **package.json** I have made a custom script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng b --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng b --prod",
    "buildAndStart": "ng build && npm start",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xlf"
  },
```

That I can launch with the command `npm run buildAndStart` so the angular project is builded and the server node is up and running.

My angular app will be listening to `http://localhost:4200/` and all the rest service at the `/api/*` path as well.

So, for example, url like:

```
http://localhost:4200/authenticated#access_token=123
http://localhost:4200/authenticated?access_token=123
```

will be evaluated by Angular, and Angular can call all the `/api/v1/myOtherServices` without any problem, even the refresh/reload will not generate any error this time.